# ¿como dar un click a una palabra que desplaza texto abajo en puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

amigos  buen día como puede darle click a esto por medio de la descripción ya que tengo otros elementos que se repiten en mi código entonces la única manera de darle click seria por el onclick quisiera saber como hacer esta prueba por medio de puppeter , espero puedan ayudar saludos!!

a onclick="descripcion("cpv2010","8305","1679",this)

Comment: Cual es el Id o class de la etiqueta que estas usando para ese evento? y en que entorno estas trabajando.

Comment: <div style="text-align: left; padding: 5px; width: 100%;"><a onclick="descripcion(&quot;cpv2010&quot;,&quot;8305&quot;,&quot;1679&quot;,this);" href="javascript:void(0);" tabindex="1678" style="text-align: left;">Ocupantes</a></div> en si este es div completo pero no lo puedo llamar por tabidex por que en otros divs de mi codigo se ´repite entonce la unica manera seria por el onclick  que tiene su descripcion no se si me doy entender y estoy utilizando puppeteer.

Comment: deverias agregar una class o id al div para que la llamada al mismo sea mas corta, suponiendo que el div tiene como **class="divParaPrueba"**  `await page.evaluate(('.divParaPrueba') => {
  descripcion("cpv2010","8305","1679",this);
});` espero te ayude

Comment: si eso lo se el detalle que esa parte del desarrollo yo no lo puedo mover y debo hacer las pruebas con los elementos que ya esta en la pagina.